# Add a date to DateTime in Entity class via Seed method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I'm trying to add a date(current, back in time and forward in time) in the Seed Method in the Configuration file, like this: `Date = 2016-05-02`, but I get an error about cannot convert `int` to `System.DateTime`. I use the Seed method to create some test object during the development. Is there a special way to add a date?

Part of the class:

```
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

Part of the Seed method:

```
Date = 2016-05-02
```

Comment: you literally used integers. please use datetime class `Date = new DateTime(2016, 5, 2);`

Comment: @SebastianSchulz Thanks it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Seed the date type this way:

```
Date = DateTime.Parse("2016-05-02");
```